# Java read a file, if it doesn't exist create it

Tags: java, file, text

here's my code

```
public String path;
public String fileName;
public static void readData() throws IOException{
    try {
        path="myPath"
        fileName="myFileName";
        fstream = new FileInputStream(path+fileName);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        //do something...//
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reading file error");
        Logger.getLogger(LeggiDaFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how to check if the fstream exists. If it doesn't exist, a new file has to be created. How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
public static void readData() throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(path, filename);

    if (!file.isFile() && !file.createNewFile())
    {
        throw new IOException("Error creating new file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    try 
    {
        // read data
    }finally
    {
        r.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also want to look at using an `InputStreamReader`, specifying the `Charset`, instead of a `FileReader` which uses the default character set...

Answer (score 2):

Something's missing in your code - there's a closing brace with no corresponding opening brace.

But to answer your question, create a `File` object first and use `exists()`, then `createNewFile()` if `exists()` returns `false`.  Pass the `File` object instead of the filename to the `FileInputStream` constructor.

BTW, it would have taken you less time to google the answer than it did to type in your question here.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the file `filename` exists in `path`, you can use `new File(path, filename).exists()`.

The [exists method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) returns true if a file or directory exists on the filesystem for the specified `File`.

To verify that the file is a file and not a directory, you can use the [isFile method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29).

See the [javadoc for java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for more information.

Comment: Or even better `new File(path,filename).exists()` which will automagically insert the correct path delimiter for the operating system you are on.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(new File("filename").exists())
   ...
```

it should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You are already catching `FileNotFoundException` and this is the very place where you know that the file you wanted to read doesn't exist and you can create it.