# Read a file, if it doesn't exist then create

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Honestly, I've searched a lot do this task so I ended up trying various methods but nothing worked until I ended up on this code. It works for me perfectly like it should, so I do not want to change my code.

The help I need is to put this code in a such a way that it begins to read a file, but if it the file doesn't exist then it will create a new file.

Code for saving data:

```
String data = sharedData.getText().toString();
try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(data.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Code for loading data:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
        String collected = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            byte[] dataArray = new byte [fis.available()];
            while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1){
                collected = new String(dataArray); 
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

So If I **add** the **saving data code** **in to** the "FileNotFoundException" **catch** of the **loading data** part then could I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add

```
File file = new File(FILENAME);
if(!file.exists())
{  
   file.createNewFile()
   // write code for saving data to the file
}
```

above

```
fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
```

This will check if there exists a `File` for the given `FILENAME` and if it doesn't it will create a new one.

Comment: Looks promising, let me give it a shot.

Comment: This is most certainly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! Finally it gets the job done although it wasn't as simple as it appeared. I had to change a things or two. First thing was to cut the whole saving data part and paste it into a new function that I named "createfileinstantly" (You could probably give that a better name :p) and then under the IF condition replace "file.createNewFile()" with "createfileinstantly();" And then it works perfectly! So please edit your answer to reflect the following things so that anyone with the same issue would get a very direct fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on `Android`, why don't you use the [API's solution for saving files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)?

Quoting:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should really read the whole document, they explain pretty well the basic ways of creating or accessing files, you can also check the [different ways of storing data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html).

But regarding your original question:

> So If I add the saving data code in to the "FileNotFoundException"
>   catch of the loading data part then could I achieve what I want?

Yes, you could achieve it.

Comment: Turns out adding the save data code in the "FileNotFoundException" crashes the app.

Comment: Of course the solution is not just to copy/paste code, the idea of the catch block is to just know if the file was not found and create it. As I said, if you're developing for an Android device I suggest you stick to the API's tools and guidelines. Or if it's only java-related I think the best (and simplest) solution would be Apoorv's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public static void readData() throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(path, filename);
    if (!file.isFile() && !file.createNewFile()){
        throw new IOException("Error creating new file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    try {
        // ...
        // read data
        // ...
    }finally{
        r.close();
    }
}
```

Ref: [Java read a file, if it doesn't exist create it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5464690/1318946)